# Transform T4 Template during Build: Method not found 'System.ReadOnlySpan'

Tags: c#, build, t4

I have a T4 template that I would like to be transformed when I build my project. When I add the following lines to my .csproj Visual Studio attempts to transform my template on build, but gets an exception.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
<PropertyGroup>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The exception:

```
Error       An exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code. The following Exception was thrown:
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Byte> System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader.GetBlobContent(System.Reflection.Metadata.BlobHandle)'.
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReaderExtensions.CreateAssemblyIdentityOrThrow(MetadataReader reader, Version version, AssemblyFlags flags, BlobHandle publicKey, StringHandle name, StringHandle culture, Boolean isReference)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReaderExtensions.ReadAssemblyIdentityOrThrow(MetadataReader reader)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PEAssembly..ctor(AssemblyMetadata owner, ImmutableArray`1 modules)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.AssemblyMetadata.GetOrCreateData()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.AssemblyMetadata.GetModules()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.AssemblyMetadata.IsValidAssembly()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonReferenceManager`2.GetMetadata(PortableExecutableReference peReference, CommonMessageProvider messageProvider, Location location, DiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonReferenceManager`2.ResolveMetadataReferences(TCompilation compilation, Dictionary`2 assemblyReferencesBySimpleName, ImmutableArray`1& references, IDictionary`2& boundReferenceDirectiveMap, ImmutableArray`1& boundReferenceDirectives, ImmutableArray`1& assemblies, ImmutableArray`1& modules, DiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.ReferenceManager.CreateAndSetSourceAssemblyFullBind(CSharpCompilation compilation)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.ReferenceManager.CreateSourceAssemblyForCompilation(CSharpCompilation compilation)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.GetRuntimeMetadataVersion(EmitOptions emitOptions)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.GetRuntimeMetadataVersion(EmitOptions emitOptions, DiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.CreateModuleBuilder(EmitOptions emitOptions, IMethodSymbol debugEntryPoint, Stream sourceLinkStream, IEnumerable`1 embeddedTexts, IEnumerable`1 manifestResources, CompilationTestData testData, DiagnosticBag diagnostics, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.CheckOptionsAndCreateModuleBuilder(DiagnosticBag diagnostics, IEnumerable`1 manifestResources, EmitOptions options, IMethodSymbol debugEntryPoint, Stream sourceLinkStream, IEnumerable`1 embeddedTexts, CompilationTestData testData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.Emit(Stream peStream, Stream metadataPEStream, Stream pdbStream, Stream xmlDocumentationStream, Stream win32Resources, IEnumerable`1 manifestResources, EmitOptions options, IMethodSymbol debugEntryPoint, Stream sourceLinkStream, IEnumerable`1 embeddedTexts, RebuildData rebuildData, CompilationTestData testData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.Emit(Stream peStream, Stream pdbStream, Stream xmlDocumentationStream, Stream win32Resources, IEnumerable`1 manifestResources, EmitOptions options, IMethodSymbol debugEntryPoint, Stream sourceLinkStream, IEnumerable`1 embeddedTexts, Stream metadataPEStream, RebuildData rebuildData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.Compile()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.Compile(String source, String inputFile, IEnumerable`1 references, Boolean debug, SupportedLanguage language, String compilerOptions). Line=0, Column=0    Company.Projects.Abstractions   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets 347
```

The template does execute successfully if I "Run Custom Tool" on it from withing Visual Studio. However I did notice that if I remove the following reference to the System.Memory assembly in my template I get a similar error when I "Run Custom Tool"

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Memory" #>
```

The error with that line removed:

```
Error       Compiling transformation: The type 'ReadOnlySpan<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.  Company.Project.Abstractions    C:\Development\Company.Project\src\SDK\Company.Project.Abstractions\Types\Template.tt   22
```

How can I get my T4 Template to transform during build? It seems like it is failing to use the System.Memory assembly during build though referencing it works fine with "Run Custom Tool."

---

Note: the instructions at [Invoke text transformation in the build process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) recommend finding this line in my project:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

I don't have that line in any of my projects. Adding it changes my target framework to .NET Framework 4 which breaks a whole lot of other things. Hopefully it isn't a necessary piece as adding that line causes even more problems.

**Update**

I reviewed my code to make sure I'm targeting netstandard2.0. Basically I built everything in a library targeting netstandard2.0 just to be sure, then brought the code back into my template.

I tried referencing System.Collections.Immutable within the template as well as install the NuGet package in the project containing the template with still no change.

Added lines for reference:

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Collections.Immutable" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Immutable" #>
```

Finally, I attempted to reduce my template to just setting and outputting a single string but this hasn't proved fruitful. I continue to get the error. But then if I remove the Import at the top and re-add it sometimes the error will go away on the next compile. Sometimes not. This has made it very hard to identify the problem code. I think my only recourse is to start from scratch, building as I go, until I generate the error.

**Update 2**
Started from scratch and found the issue. Just including this assembly triggers the MissingMethodException, even without any code using it:

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Memory" #>
```

However, if I remove it adding this line back in triggers another exception:

```
var myArray = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonArray>(fileJson);
```

The exception:

```
Compiling transformation: The type 'ReadOnlySpan<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

So it seems to do what I want to do I need to reference System.Memory, but even in the simplest code I can't reference System.Memory without introducing the original exception. For now I'm going to see if I can use alternative libraries to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

Add assembly directive with `System.Collections.Immutable`. That may solve your problem but could also introduce some additional ones. Be aware that it is safer to use only `netstandard2.0` APIs in the template code. The confusion comes from the fact that running the template tranformation via the custom tool in Visual Studio and running it in a build via MSBuild uses different hosts with different prerequisites.

Comment: Added an update. In brief an assembly directive and making sure its netstandard2.0 compatible didn't resolve it. I also found the error won't reliably go away if I remove problem code, making it hard to pinpoint the exact problem by trial and error.

Comment: "making sure its netstandard2.0 compatible" -- but it's not, you're referencing spans. Spans aren't .netstandard2.0 compatible.

Comment: I added another update. I'm not referencing spans directly. But I am referencing JsonSerializer.Deserialize from System.Text.Json, which requires a reference to System.Memory which triggers the error. Though I'm able to do all that without needing a reference to System.Memory in a project with T4 and targeting netstandard2.0.

Comment: I gave up on loading own compiled assemblies in T4 templates. Could not make it work reliably across platforms and scenarios. More reliable (but not 100%) is using code snippets (even with references to System.Text.Json).